# Will a battery connected to the Earth eventually deplete?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, batteries

I've been thinking about this, and my answer is leaning towards yes, but I couldn't find any definitive answer by Googling.

If the higher potential side of a typical battery is connected by wire to a spike driven into the ground, will it eventually deplete?

My thought process is that the voltage difference will cause current to flow between the electrode and the earth, causing the battery to eventually "die," just as if it was connected in a circuit.

However, I also wonder what the difference is between this situation and shorting the battery. Connecting the anode and cathod of a battery together will cause it to heat up and damage itself, but will the same happen if its connected to ground? Isn't it (physically) the same situation?

Comment: *"My thought process is that the voltage difference will cause current to flow"* - what voltage difference?  If you connect one terminal of the battery to the Earth, there is no voltage difference between that terminal and Earth.  Yes, there is a voltage difference between the other, *unconnected* terminal but, since it *is* unconnected, there is zero current in or out of this terminal.  How could there be a discharge current?

Comment: All of the answers to this question state that potential (which the unit of measurement for is Voltage (V)) is relative. However, none of the answers say what the difference in potential to either terminal on the battery is in reference to a properly installed ground rod. Does anyone know what the potential is? The question assumes a properly installed ground rod and a near 0 ohm resistance connection from the positive terminal on the battery to the ground rod. It would be nice to know the actual voltage difference between the two!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the thing about potential/voltage. Potential/voltage is a measure of **difference** in the, say, potential energy between two points in space. So the correct term is actually: "**potential/voltage difference**" when we talk about that stuff. So when you talk about batteries, the higher potential side of the battery is higher, with respect to, the lower side. It has nothing to do with anything else, you, me, your computer, the Sun or Earth. Technically, the higher potential side of the battery is not higher/lower than earth.

Here is what happens when you touch the "+" side of the battery to ground:
[image]

Soil resistance might be very low depending on the type of soil. However, air resistance is much higher which will prevent battery discharge.

By the way, both soil and air can conduct current with free ions. (Higher voltages cause big ionization i.e. lightnings) (Pouring salt water in soil also helps lower soil resistance)

Now, if you throw your battery in soil and pour some saltwater in there, you'll definitely be seeing a discharge!

Comment: Maybe you could explain how this picture is different from both terminals being in contact with air? If air conducts a meaningful amount of current from the soil to the negative terminal, then should it not also conduct a meaningful amount of current from the positive terminal to the negative even when the battery does not touch the soil?

Answer (score 2):

First off, every battery will die eventually, due to self-discharge.  So eventually the answer to every one of these is "yes" for that reason.

If you connect *only* the high potential side of the battery to the ground, it will not noticeably change the process.  Unless you have a circuit, current does not flow.  There will be some *minor* current which goes through the air to complete the circuit, but that will be very minor indeed compared to self discharge.  You won't notice the effect.

Connecting *both* sides of the battery can discharge the battery faster.  The ground, like all materials, has a resistivity.  You will have a circuit and you will deplete the battery.  How fast you deplete it depends on a lot of factors, such as the water content of the ground and how far apart the wires are.

Do note that the terms "Earth" and "Ground" are just reference points in electrical engineering.  "Earth" typically *does* in fact mean that you connected the wire to the earth beneath your feet, but that's only a convention.  There's nothing magical about the dirt.  It behaves like everything else.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What is the difference here between the higher potential end of a battery being connected to the ground and it being connected to its negative terminal? What's special about the lower potential of the negative terminal that makes its connection a circuit while a connection to the ground isn't a circuit?

Comment: If you can draw a loop that current can flow through, then it's a circuit.  In the case of a shorted battery, that loop is "positive terminal, through the wire, into the negative terminal, (and through the battery)"  If you only have one terminal connected to ground and one terminal not connected to anything, you can't find any circuit (other than "one terminal, into the ground, into the air, to the other terminal," but the resistance of the air is incredibly high, so *very* little current flows this way... most of the time we'd just say "no current flows" and be done with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will deplete faster than if left unconnected, but you need excellent earth connection, that is not easily achieved.

In order to explain, we have to address one of the answers, implying that electric potential was a relative thing. Wrong: it is an absolute quantity, representing the excess or deficit of electrons in a body.

The Earth is a very large body that conducts electricity because of its huge section, and whose potential is very close to 0V. It can sink a lot of current and remain at this potential due to its mass. There is nothing magical about it.

Now, electricity flows where there is a conductive path between points of different electric potential. Electrons are repelled by negative charges, and attracted by positive ones. They certainly do not "know" anything, whether it is the space location of the source, or whether the conductive path it is on has been closed or not. That - to address another answer - would be the magical thing.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcez0ri9yPY) is a video of an electromagnetic finite-element simulation (based on Ansys HFSS) where you can see picosecond after picosecond that current starts flowing at the source before there is any way to know whether the circuit is closed or not, because it is one light-year long.

Other examples of open circuits include monopole antennae, capacitors, and the many cases of static discharges, ranging from ESD to lightning strikes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Guys you're missing the main point. How battery chemistry works ? Current flowing from positive to negative right ? So earth has nothing to do with DC (batteries) unless both terminals ( +&-) touching ground at the same time but earth resistance is higher than any other conductive so the discharge rate will be much lower. If you connect either of the terminal to the earth it'll do nothing cause earth is not connected to other terminal not battery plates or electrolytes. No chemical changes inside the battery means no charge or discharge. On the other hand electricity in your house is different you can simply discharge AC power to the earth by touching it which is potentially dangerous.

And one point to remember : don't misunderstand with battery self discharge cause every battery will discharge itself over time it has nothing to do with earth.

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell if you place both the neg and pos leads of a battery in wet or damp soil you have made a completed circuit, which in time will drain the battery, which is the perfect method of collecting night crawlers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).